# Property injection using Unity attribute [Dynamic] in Console app not working

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, console-application

```
public class Program { //Entrypoint
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IMetric>(new InjectionFactory(c => BuildMetric()));
          ...
          SomeClassThatCallsLoader kk = new SomeClassThatCallsLoader();
          kk.DoSomething();  //Loader gets instantiated in here..
    }
}

   public class Loader {
     [Dynamic]
     public IMetric Metric { get; set;}
    }
```

Why does the Metric property not get set?. Console app. Do I have to register the container? Where and how?

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection containers (such as Unity) don't do any magic - they work by resolving instances **and their dependencies** through the container. This means all types must be registered with the container (either explicitly or by using conventions).

```
        // Composition Root
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterFactory<IMetric>(c => BuildMetric());
        container.RegisterType<ILoader, Loader>();
        container.RegisterType<ISomeClassThatDependsOnLoader, SomeClassThatDependsOnLoader>();
```

The recommended way to inject dependencies is to accept them through the class constructor, rather than using property injection. Use property injection only when it makes sense to do so.

But here is your example rewritten to include both property injection and constructor injection, as well as a factory method (which is only static here because you didn't provide an example of how you did it - I don't recommend using static methods if it is possible to avoid them).

```
using System;
using Unity;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Composition Root
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterFactory<IMetric>(c => BuildMetric());
        container.RegisterType<ILoader, Loader>();
        container.RegisterType<ISomeClassThatDependsOnLoader, SomeClassThatDependsOnLoader>();

        // Application (runtime)
        var kk = container.Resolve<ISomeClassThatDependsOnLoader>(); //Loader gets instantiated in here..
        kk.DoSomething();
    }

    public static IMetric BuildMetric()
    {
        return new Metric();
    }
}

public interface ILoader
{
    IMetric Metric { get; set; } // Property Injection
}

public class Loader : ILoader
{
    [Dependency]
    public IMetric Metric { get; set; }
}

public interface IMetric
{
}

public class Metric : IMetric
{
}

public interface ISomeClassThatDependsOnLoader
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class SomeClassThatDependsOnLoader : ISomeClassThatDependsOnLoader
{
    private readonly ILoader loader;
    public SomeClassThatDependsOnLoader(ILoader loader) // Constructor Injection
    {
        this.loader = loader ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loader));
    }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something with this.loader.Metric...
    }
}
```

So, your example of property injection has 2 problems:

1. You are not registering the `Loader` type with the Unity container.
2. You are using the wrong attribute. It should be `[Dependency]`, not `[Dynamic]`.

Note that since all types that depend on `IMetric` should take a reference to `ILoader`, not `Loader` (otherwise it cannot be swapped or mocked). But if classes that depend on `ILoader` require access to `IMetric`, then `ILoader` must expose `IMetric` as part of its interface. I don't recommend you do it like above, it would make far more sense to inject `IMetric` through the class constructor of each class that depends on it. I am only doing as above to show you how property injection works, but this is not a design choice I would recommend for most cases.

## The Recommended Way

Here is an example using "normal" dependency injection techniques:

```
using System;
using Unity;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Composition Root
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IMetric, Metric>();
        container.RegisterType<IApplication, Application>();

        // Application (runtime)

        // Note that in a console application, you generally only call 
        // container.Resolve() once followed by a method to set things 
        // in motion. The type you resolve here should represent the
        // ENTIRE console application, and you would typically pass 
        // the args (if used) through to that class to process them. 
        // No business logic should go here, only code to read config files,
        // register types, and set the application in motion.
        var app = container.Resolve<IApplication>(); // Application and Metric get instantiated here...
        app.Run(args);
    }
}
public interface IMetric
{ }

public class Metric : IMetric
{ }

public interface IApplication
{
    void Run(string[] args);
}

public class Application : IApplication
{
    private readonly IMetric metric;
    public Application(IMetric metric) // Constructor Injection
    {
        this.metric = metric ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(metric));
    }
    public void Run(string[] args)
    {
        // Do something with this.metric...
    }
}
```

Note that if you use constructor injection, you can eliminate the `Loader` type altogether (assuming you can do without it). You can also remove the factory method, which makes the code much simpler.